# What happened when market status change from pre-market trading hours to standard trading hours?

Tags: equities, market-data, algorithmic-trading, market-microstructure, exchange

Now we can place orders in pre-market trading hours, from 4 am to 9:30 am. And then we go into standard trading hours, 9:30 am to 4:30 pm. But I wonder then when will the Market Order Auction happen?

According to this doc: https://www.nyse.com/markets/nyse-arca/market-info, there will be a market order freeze period, does it mean technically the pre-market is from 4 am to 9:29 am?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The timing of events is described in more detail here "NYSE Arca conducts three single-price auctions each trading day  - Early Open, Core Open and Closing Auction" https://www.nyse.com/markets/nyse-arca/trading-info As I understand it from 9:29 to 9:30 there is only a freeze on "cancel and replace of MOO Orders and LOO Orders". These are not allowed.